# Firefox method of using mouse x,y not same as Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

My program uses the mouse movement to control the location of a graphic on the screen, the graphic moves with the mouse.  This works as intended in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox. Is there a html or javascript method that will work in all three browsers?

Here are the code steps that are working in Chrome & IE: (full program link here) http://www.midaslink.com/mastermind.htm

```
<body onMousemove=setup()>
<img id = "spot" name = "spot" src = "blank_dot.gif">
```

this calls setup()

```
function setup()
{
   mouseX = window.event.x;
   mouseY = window.event.y;
   window.status = mouseX + " " + mouseY;
   this.document.all.spot.style.left = mouseX - 15;
   this.document.all.spot.style.top = mouseY - 10;
}
```

throughout the program, spot is changed by the user clicking on a graphic, which changes the spot .src to the new graphic as in the following:

```
function green()
{
   document.spot.src = "green_dot.gif"
}

function red()
{
   document.spot.src = "red_dot.gif"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Often times, browser differences drive developers to use frameworks like jQuery to normalize things like this.

quirksmode.com is a good resource if you don't want to go that route. Here is what you are looking for: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    // posx and posy contain the mouse position relative to the document
    // Do something with this information
}
```